# Removing unwanted strings, signs and space from a pandas dataframe list

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a Department column in pandas data frame as following

| Date | Department |
| --- | --- |
| Friday, 1 April 2022 | S220- Department of Transport |
| Thursday, 26 August 2021 | S220 Department of Transport |
| Friday, 1 April 2022 | S221- Department of Land, Water, Planning |
| Thursday, 26 August 2021 | S221 Department of Land, Water, Planning |

Since , in the source data, the department column is erroneous, for example, while S220- Department of Transport and S220 Department of Transport refers to the same department, when I pivot this data I get two Department of Transport columns. I expect one Department of transport columns. Currently I am using find and replace , but there are hundreds of agencies.

How Can I get the data in the following format

| Date | Department |
| --- | --- |
| Friday, 1 April 2022 | Department of Transport |
| Thursday, 26 August 2021 | Department of Transport |
| Friday, 1 April 2022 | Department of Land, Water, Planning |
| Thursday, 26 August 2021 | Department of Land, Water, Planning |

The string format should start at the D and take in all including ',' s to the right of D
I appreciate your kind suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to iterate on each row of department and remove leading undesirable characters as bellow. This is not very scalable but it might be sufficient

```
import pandas as pd
dep = ["S220- Department of Transport", "S220 Department of Transport" ,"S221- Department of Land, Water, Planning", "S221 Department of Land, Water, Planning"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Department": dep})

df["Department"] = df["Department"].apply(lambda x: "".join(c for c in x[1:] if not c.isdigit() and c != "-").strip())

print(df.head())
                            Department
0              Department of Transport
1              Department of Transport
2  Department of Land, Water, Planning
3  Department of Land, Water, Planning
```

Answer (score 2):

here is one way to do it to get

> The string format should start at the D and take in all including ','
> s to the right of D

```
df['Department'] = df['Department'].str.extract(r'(D.*)')
df
```

```
    Date                        Department
0   Friday, 1 April 2022        Department of Transport
1   Thursday, 26 August 2021    Department of Transport
2   Friday, 1 April 2022        Department of Land, Water, Planning
3   Thursday, 26 August 2021    Department of Land, Water, Planning
```